# Apache Beam for Google Cloud DataFlow - 404 errors when using BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm experiencing an issue when I run a Beam DataFlow (written in Java), for data entry into Google BigQuery. The issue occurs in my development environment and also on the production environment.

I'm processing multiple items of data through a Beam pipeline on separate threads. I'm processing by using a `ParDo` that transforms the received data using an `apply` over a `PCollection`. For the transformed data, I then attempt to write it to Google BigQuery.

I'm attempting to write my transformed data into BigQuery with a routine that looks like the following:

```
transformedData
   .apply("Load fact data",
         BigQueryIO.<ValidatedDataRecord>write()
         .to(new LoadDataFact.DynamicFactTableDestination(dataType.label))
         .withFormatFunction(new LoadDataFact.FactSerializationFn())
         .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
         .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

The significant thing here is that I'm using the following:

```
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
```

... because I want a new table to be created if doesn't already exist

The issue is that when new data becomes part of the dataflow, and that data requires a new dataset for the data, I frequently (but don't always) get the following 404 error:

```
Exception thrown in class : com.myOrg.myPackage.myClass Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
"code" : 404,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Not found: Table my-project:my-dataset.my-table",
"reason" : "notFound"
} ],
"message" : "Not found: Table my-project:my-dataset.my-table",
"status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

I've investigated what goes on in the underlying Beam SDKs Java Core library. What's happening is that when the 1st new item of data is processed, the `CreateTables.class` in the 'Beam SDKs Java Core' library should try to create a new table, and if successful it adds an entry to the static `CreateTables.createdTables` collection for the new table, to indicate that the table is created. The 404 error seems to occur subsequent to the table being created (although sometimes, the table fails entirely to be created). I'm not sure what's causing this behaviour, or what triggers the 404 error (the error message doesn't give much info). This type of error in BigQuery is usually because the table doesn't exist at whatever stage it's being accessed.

The `CreateTables.class` is part of the following Beam SDKs Java Core library:

```
C:\Users\my.username\.m2\repository\org\apache\beam\beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform\2.5.0\beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform-2.5.0.jar!\org\apache\beam\sdk\io\gcp\bigquery\CreateTables.class
```

I've raised this a a bug on the Beam Jira - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7195

I tried updating my Beam SDKs Java Core library to v 2.12.0, but for some reason the dataflow stopped working altogether.

Is there a way I can work around the issue? I'm using a custom class to override the `DynamicDestinations` class that Beam uses for processing (this is the way that the documentation specifies that dynamic data destinations should be implemented - see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#using-dynamic-destinations).

My custom class looks like this, and the `getTable` method is called during the process of each item of data, to determine the table that the data should be added to:

```
public class LoadDataFact {

    public static class DynamicFactTableDestination extends DynamicDestinations<ValidatedDataRecord, String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1234561111111123456L;
        private static final String projectID = "my-project";
        private String dataType = "none";
        private String elementDuration = "unknown";

        public DynamicFactTableDestination(String dataType) {
            this.dataType = dataType;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<ValidatedDataRecord> element) {    

            return element.getValue().DatasetName;
        }

        @Override
        public TableDestination getTable(String destination) {

            try {
                return new TableDestination(new TableReference()
                        .setProjectId(projectID)
                        .setDatasetId(destination)
                        .setTableId(String.format("data_for_%s",this.dataType)), "Data staging table",
                        new TimePartitioning()
                                .setType("DAY")
                                .setField("created_date_time"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myOrg.myNamespace</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact-name</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <beam.version>2.5.0</beam.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-exec-plugin.version>1.6.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-exec-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
           <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
           <configuration>
              <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                 <pluginExecutions>
                    <pluginExecution>
                       <pluginExecutionFilter>
                          <groupId>
                             org.apache.maven.plugins
                          </groupId>
                          <artifactId>
                             maven-compiler-plugin
                          </artifactId>
                          <versionRange>
                             [@maven-compiler-plugin.version@,)
                          </versionRange>
                          <goals>
                             <goal>compile</goal>
                             <goal>testCompile</goal>
                          </goals>
                       </pluginExecutionFilter>
                       <action>
                          <ignore></ignore>
                       </action>
                    </pluginExecution>
                 </pluginExecutions>
              </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
      <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.16</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Very detail question!!!. Just wondering, and maybe I'm missing something obvious, why you are doing _synchronized_ on a _static_ map object `private static Set<String> createdTables = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap());
`. Typically _synchronized_ is done when 2 separate threads access the same object but in your case, it's a static object which can't be changed

Comment: Thanks @Tamir Klein - I'm not doing this step, it occurs in the 3rd party Beam library.

Comment: Defiantly looks like a bug which you have opened. My suggestion to you in your over-ride class use [reading-with-a-query-string](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-with-a-query-string) and in your select simply put `SELECT FROM TABLE LIMIT 0`. Now you can add your _synchronized_ logic around this check which should work

Comment: Thanks @Tamir Klein, however I'm not really sure what your suggesting, and how this would work. Firstly, the `getTable` method in my over-ride class is _always_ called. So the first item of data causes it to be called, and it returns the _description_ of the table, which is used to create the table. For subsequent data, the method is still used, to determine which table should be _read_. So any logic in there that tries to read the table will fail first time, and the table will never be created.

Comment: @Tamir Klein, I updated (simplified) the question as I discovered that a new thread can come along and attempt to create the table, which is why the table was magically appearing in the `createdTables` collection. I've also discovered that the 404 can occur even when the table is successfully created and other data is successfully written. If you have any ideas or suggestions, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: After reading again your question what I understand is that as part of the load you use this `withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)` which instruct BigQuery to create the table. The `DynamicDestinations` simply set the table properties which are used by BigQuery during the load. So maybe your problem is elsewhere. Are you always adding to the same dataset and same project are any of those properties new in the process?

Comment: Yes, I'm always adding to the same dataset and project. The 404 message specifically says that it's the existing table that isn't being found. And the data should always be the same

Comment: Sorry, So maybe OP will be able to help. Hope you will solve this soon.

Comment: Did you supply schema? When I use create-if-needed, I also set the schema for the table.

Comment: Hi @Brachi, thanks - yes, I'm not showing it in my code example however I do set the schema. The table is usually created successfully, sometimes not. If you have any ideas on what may be causing the 404, please let me know!

Comment: The error you show seems to be directly raised by the BigQuery API Call. When you say that the table is created and the data is being written you saw this error appears? Because the error has the info of what is not being found, if that's the case this could be an issue with the BigQuery API itself. If data has already been written and the 404 error appears, I can only imagine it being caused by wrong information being sent to the API. If you are using the same project and the same dataset, consider using the getDestionation method to get the dataType instead of using it for the DatasetName